# Equating the expression $\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-b)}+\frac{(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{(x-c)(x-a)}{(b-c)(b-a)}-1=0$

Tags: polynomials

I understand that this is too easy a question for most of us here but still I ask it for one reason.

I thought that putting $x=a,x=b,x=c$ makes the above equation $=0$ in each case. Hence number of distinct, real $x$ for which the equation is $=0$ should be $=3$ but the answer is $>3$.I am a little confused why? Any light on this small query?Or to put it straight where am I wrong?

I think I got the answer , yes for sure putting $x=a,x=b,x=c$ makes the equation $=0$ in each case. But fundamentally it can also happen that for some real $x=x_0 \ne a \space or  \space b \space or \space c$ for which $\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-b)}+\frac{(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{(x-c)(x-a)}{(b-c)(b-a)}=1$.Hence that makes the number of distinct real $x$ for which the equation is 0

Comment: I think you assumed that the polynomial has degree $2$. It's not the case. It's the $0$ polynomial, as indicated by the roots

Comment: hint: it looks like Lagrange approximation polynomial.

Comment: Ok @zwim let me try . No answers please. Let me try.

Comment: It's Lagrange interpolation for the constant function $1$. So the expression is identically zero.